# Android dfp inmobi mediation

Tags: android, ads, google-dfp, inmobi

we integrated Google DFP in our Android app. Now we would like to add support with InMobi but I found no guide to add the mediation of InMobi through DFP.
Is there any guide / tutorial / example?

This is the code we have used for dfp:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView;
...

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

   mAdView = (PublisherAdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
   PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build();
   mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the InMobi products team. You'll need to follow the steps below:

1. Create a Ad Unit and Placement for InMobi under the Inventory section
2. Create an order and line item for InMobi
3. Under the Line Item, add a creative as SDK mediation and select InMobi as the network.
4. In the input box, please enter your property id available in your InMobi Dashboard
5. Integrate your app with the Google Ads SDK and use your DFP Ad unit id in that. Along with the Google Ads SDK, please include the InMobi Adapter and the InMobi Android SDK in your project.

More details on SDK mediation are available on the [InMobi support portal](https://www.inmobi.com/support/integration/?page_id=12&id=26219383&parentid=22095493&title=AdMob%20Mediation%20Adapter%20Guides)